# Side-menu in navigation-bar in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am confused in the use of `Navigator` with react-native-side-menu. In my code I use navigator and `NavigatorIOS` for side-menu in navbar,but that code is not working in Android, because of the usage of `NavigatorIOS`. Now I am trying to convert my code to usage of `Navigator` in react-native.

- Here is the my code with the usage of **NavigatorIOS**:

> ```
> var Basic = React.createClass({
>   getInitialState() {
>     return {
>       navigationBarHidden: false
>     };
>   },
>
>   showSideBar () {
>       return this.refs.sidemenu.openMenu();
>   },
>
>   getNavigator(){
>     if (this.refs.nav){
>       return this.refs.nav.navigator;
>     }else{
>       return undefined;
>     }
>   },
>   LogOut(){
>     this.refs.sidemenu.closeMenu();
>     this.props.navigator.popToTop();
>   },
>   render(){
>     //alert("renderEmail:"+this.props.email);
>     return (
>       <SideMenu 
>         ref="sidemenu"
>         touchToClose={true}
>         disableGestures={true}
>         menu={
>           <Menu
>             getNavigator={this.getNavigator}
>             showSideBar={this.showSideBar}
>             LogOut={this.LogOut}
>           />
>         }
>        >
>           <NavigatorIOS
>             ref = "nav"
>             shouldUpdate={true}
>             style={styles.container}
>             barTintColor='#1A8A29'
>             tintColor='white'
>             titleTextColor='white'
>             initialRoute={{
>               component: BecomeMember,
>               title:'Become Member',
>               leftButtonIcon: require('image!menu1'),
>               onLeftButtonPress: ()=> {this.showSideBar(); },
>               rightButtonTitle: 'Log Out',
>               onRightButtonPress: ()=> {this.LogOut();},
>               passProps: {email:this.props.email,userId:this.props.userId},
>             }}
>             />
>       </SideMenu>
>     );
>
>   }
> });
> ```

when i wrote using navigatorIOS side-menu works correctly but using navigator in react-native-side-menu it not working, here is the code using **Navigator**

```
 showSideBar () {
      return this.refs.sidemenu.openMenu();
  },

  getNavigator(){
    if (this.refs.nav){
      return this.refs.nav.navigator;
    }else{
      return undefined;
    }
  },
  LogOut(){
    this.refs.sidemenu.closeMenu();
    this.props.navigator.popToTop();
  },
  render(){
    //alert("renderEmail:"+this.props.email);
    var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
    if(index > 0){
      return(
        <TouchableHighlight style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={() =>{
          if(index > 0){
            navigator.pop();
          }
        }}>
        <Text>Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }else{
      return (
        <Text onPress={this.showSideBar()}>Main</Text>
        )
    }
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState){
    return <Text style={styles.navBarTitle}>MaxWords</Text>
  }
}
    return (
      <SideMenu ref="sidemenu" touchToClose={true} disableGestures={true} menu={<Menu getNavigator={this.getNavigator} showSideBar={this.showSideBar} LogOut={this.LogOut}/>}>
          <Navigator
            ref="nav"
            shouldUpdate={true}
            style={{flex:1}}
            initialRoute={{name:'My Profile',component:MyProfile,leftButtonIcon: require('image!menu1'),
              onLeftButtonPress: ()=> {this.showSideBar()},index:0}}
            renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
              if(route.component){
                return React.createElement(route.component, {...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route});
              }
            }}
            navigationBar = {<Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}  style={styles.navBar}/>}/>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
```

when i calling the function `this.showSideBar()`, it throws an error as shown in the image below
 [image]

Can any one give me suggestions on how to solve this and how to use `Navigator` with side-menu in react-native ? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try either changing `onPress={this.showSideBar()}` to `onPress={this.showSideBar}` or `onPress={() => this.showSideBar()}`

Comment: @schinknbrot,I tried like that also it shows the error like as mentioned above

Comment: I am not completely sure about the `this` scope in this case.
Could you try to assign `this.showSideBar` to a local variable inside the `render` method?

Comment: yah even it shows an error like undefined is not an object(evaluating'this.refs.sidemenu'), If possible can you check the above code using NavigatorIOS, It's working for me in IOS,But throws an error in android,So can you change the NavigatorIOS to navigator, And I tried that can you check and give me the suggestions where i wrote wrong.

Comment: could you try set the ref like:
`ref={(sideMenu) => this._sideMenu = sideMenu}`

Comment: when i declare this ref in Side menu and declaring the function showSidebar inside the render method, Then it shows an error like undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.refs.sidemenu'), i declare like this:<SideMenu ref={(sideMenu) => this._sideMenu = sideMenu} >

Comment: you also have to update `showSideBar () { return this._sideMenu.openMenu();}`

Comment: Getting error like this:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this._sidemenu.openMenu')

Comment: at last option I sometimes log `this` to see what the current scope is. maybe this helps

Answer (score 1):

Either

1) Add it via `passProps` to the component. e.g.

```
initialRoute={{
    component: YourComponent,
    passProps: {
        onLeftButtonPress: this.showSideBa,
    },
    (..other stuff here)
}}
```

or

2) Add it to the `renderScene` as a property. e.g.

```
renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = route.component;
    var navBar = route.navigationBar;

    return (
      <View style={styles.navigator}>
        <Component
          {...route.passProps}
          navigator={navigator}
          route={route}
          onLeftButtonPress={this.showSideBar}/>
      </View>
    );
},
```

and update your `renderScene()` in the Navigator to point to the function instead.

```
initialRoute={{
    component: YourComponent,
    (..other stuff here),
    renderScene={this.renderScene}
}}
```

Using method 2 will pass it down to every scene that get rendered through the navigator.